# Chrome Console Error:404

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, console

I am getting two console errors on thin [page](http://isotopethemes.com/extenso/index.html). The first error is from jquery-latest.js and masterslider.js. The second error is from jquery.themepunch.tools.min.

I've been trying from hours to solve this, the error is quite clear but I am not sure of the solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Page Link: http://isotopethemes.com/extenso/index.html

jquery-latest.js link: http://isotopethemes.com/extenso/js/jquery-latest.js

masterslider.js link: http://isotopethemes.com/extenso/js/master-slider/masterslider.js

Comment: I'm not getting any error

Comment: Well.. I think this is beyond our reach if uncompressed js isn't available for us. The problem may lies in image loading, sine the error does not appear until the slider moves. But some variables is `undefined` so you get a 404 instead. Try setting some breakpoints in your code and inspect what happens there.

Comment: thank you @HerringtonDarkholme. I will try doing that

Comment: @towc: thank you for the comment, I am using chrome on Win 8. At least gives me hope that there are no error for someone else.